# Wired Internet connection stopped working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS periodically

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, network-manager

I have faced peculiar problem, let me explain the whole history.
At first I have started to use Ubuntu 12.04LTS for my simulation purpose. But I recognised that internet connection (wired) stopped working but topbar in internet wire connection setting showed that the connection was okay, even if I pinged in the terminal with my IP it showed that data were transferred normally. Then I have disable/enable networking  simultaneously, then browser works. I am using ubuntu with this problem for a long time (almost one year..), yesterday I have upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04LTS with a hope that the problem will be resolved......but alas! problem is same. Now, it stops several times in a day.   Here is the screenshots of pinging of my ip [http://i57.tinypic.com/206fmhe.jpg] when internet connection doesn't work in my pc. It is also noted that at this if I click on software updater it also asked to check my network connection.....

```
    mukut@mukut-Endeavor-MR3300:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82566DC Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1b:fc:e5:2c:8e
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k duplex=full firmware=1.1-0 ip=172.17.1.24 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 memory:fe9c0000-fe9dffff memory:fe9fb000-fe9fbfff ioport:e880(size=32)
```

Hope someone can solve the issue.

BR
mukut